# lodash _.filter return empty array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I'm stuck in Angular.js using  lodash `_.filter`.

```js
$scope.test = [
    { name: 'FirstName', items: ["Phone", "Tablet"] },
    { name: 'FirstName', items: ["TV"] },
];
$scope.items = [
    { item: "Phone" },
    { item: "Tablet" }
]
$scope.fined = [];
$scope.fined = _.filter(test, _.matches(items));
console.log(fined)// result []
```

I Expected:

```
$scope.fined= [{name:'FirstName',items:["Phone","Tablet"]}];
```

I don't know why but `_.filter` return empty array :-(

Some ideas?

Comment: `matches` expects an Object and you try to pass an Array: https://lodash.com/docs#matches

Comment: The same result without array.

Comment: First: You try to compare `array of objects` with `array of strings`. Second: `matches` have problem with compare arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_.matches` works in a way that you pass an object whose key value pairs are then being checked in the returned predicate function. So your case should look like this:

```
var test = [
    { name: 'FirstName', items: ["Phone", "Tablet"] },
    { name: 'FirstName', items: ["TV"] },
];
var items = { items:  ["Phone", "Tablet"] };

var fined = _.filter(test, _.matches(items));
console.log(fined);
```

Quoting the docs:

> This method supports comparing arrays, booleans, Date objects, numbers, Object objects, regexes, and strings. Objects are compared by their own, not inherited, enumerable properties.

Note that this will *not* work when using underscore as this will not do the deep checking on the Array elements.

See [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/stwhreyd/)